# How to get Semester Average

Tags: python, file

I have code that will take a legend of grades, and number of grades and then return values for it. I have everything right except for the semester average. Here's the formula to finding semester average:

```
homework average * 0.2 + quiz average * 0.2 + project average * 0.6.
```

My code works well with homework averages, quiz averages, and project averages but not with semester average.
Here's what I have written:

```
def get_header():  
    gb_data = open('gb_data.txt','r')
    header = gb_data.readline()
    return header.strip()

def get_content():  
    gb_data = open('gb_data.txt','r')
    content = gb_data.readlines()
    del content[0]
    return content

hw_pos = []
project_pos = []
quiz_pos =  []

header_list = get_header()
header_list = header_list.split(", ")
header_list_index = enumerate(header_list)
for index, target in header_list_index:
    if target == "hw":
        hw_pos.append(index)
    elif target == "quiz":
        quiz_pos.append(index)
    elif target == "project":
        project_pos.append(index)

content_list = get_content()

avg_dict = {}

for element in content_list:
    element = element.strip().split(", ")

    name = element[0] + ', ' + element[1]
    hw_avg = sum([int(element[i]) for i in hw_pos]) / len(hw_pos)
    quiz_avg = sum([int(element[i]) for i in quiz_pos]) / len(quiz_pos)
    project_avg = sum([int(element[i]) for i in project_pos]) / len(project_pos)
    sem_avg = hw_avg * 0.2 + quiz_avg * 0.2 + project_avg * 0.6
    avg_dict.update({name:(hw_avg, quiz_avg, project_avg, sem_avg)})


f = open('avg.txt', 'w')
for name, avg in avg_dict.items():
  dataline = name + ": hw avg = " + str(round(avg[0], 2)) + ", quiz avg = " + str(round(avg[2], 2)) + ", proj avg = " + str(round(avg[1], 2)) + ", sem avg = " + str(round(avg[2], 2)) + "\n"
  f.write(dataline)

f.close()
```

Here's an example of an input I put in:

```
last, first, hw, hw, project, quiz, hw, hw, hw, quiz, hw, hw, project
Cat, Figaro, 57, 58, 71, 93, 56, 86, 90, 99, 55, 99, 88
```

The top line is the legend so ignore that, my code handles that
Here's what should be given back:

```
Cat, Figaro: hw avg = 71.57, quiz avg = 96.0, proj avg = 79.5, sem avg = 81.21
```

Here's what I actually get back:

```
Cat, Figaro: hw avg = 71.57, quiz avg = 96.0, proj avg = 79.5, sem avg = 96.0
```

I want to make them match EXACTLY, down to every character. I just need to know how to round it correctly. This is NOT homework and is just a project to understand files better, I'm very close!! My name is Scarlett btw please help!!!

Comment: Consider using Pandas, Python's popular data analysis library, designed for such calculations in more efficient methods than by lists.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo this line:

> dataline = name + ": hw avg = " + str(round(avg[**0**], 2)) + ", quiz avg = " + str(round(avg[**2**], 2)) + ", proj avg = " + str(round(avg[**1**], 2)) + ", sem avg = " + str(round(avg[**2**], 2)) + "\n"

It should be

> dataline = name + ": hw avg = " + str(round(avg[**0**], 2)) + ", quiz avg = " + str(round(avg[**1**], 2)) + ", proj avg = " + str(round(avg[**2**], 2)) + ", sem avg = " + str(round(avg[**3**], 2)) + "\n"

instead. The calculation is fine, just the output was messed up (You printed 0, 2, 1, 2 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3). To prevent mistakes like this in the future, maybe take a look at Pandas with its column names? Pandas is probably an overkill in this case, but a very powerful tool for table-based calculations.

Comment: That worked for computing the project and semester average, but somehow broke my quiz average??

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from statistics import mean

legend = ['last', 'first', 'hw', 'hw', 'project', 'quiz', 'hw', 'hw', 'hw', 'quiz', 'hw', 'hw', 'project']
grades = ['Cat', 'Figaro', 57, 58, 71, 93, 56, 86, 90, 99, 55, 99, 88]

hw_avg = mean([g for l, g in zip(legend, grades) if l == 'hw'])
quiz_avg = mean([g for l, g in zip(legend, grades) if l == 'quiz'])
project_avg = mean([g for l, g in zip(legend, grades) if l == 'project'])
sem_avg = hw_avg * 0.2 + quiz_avg * 0.2 + project_avg * 0.6

print(f'{grades[0]}, {grades[1]}: hw avg = {hw_avg:.2f}, quiz avg = {quiz_avg:.2f}, project avg = {project_avg:.2f}, sem avg = {sem_avg:.2f}')
```

It gives me the following:

```
Cat, Figaro: hw avg = 71.57, quiz avg = 96.00, project avg = 79.50, sem avg = 81.21
```

Note that I'm just using statistics.mean as it makes the code cleaner. But you could do the same with a method like yours.